# ComboxBox Data Binding and Default Selected Item using WCF RIA Services

Tags: silverlight, combobox, wcf-ria-services, selecteditem

I am trying to bind the data to ComboBox using WCF RIA. Only for data binding is fine but on the same time I want to be already selected for the specified item after binding. For this case, I don't know how can I do to achieve this. May be the way that my data binding also wrong.

Here is my Entity

```
public class Customer
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Key()]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}
```

Here is WCF RIA Service

```
public class CustomerDomainService : DomainService
{

    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers()
    {
            List<Customer> rtnList = new List<Customer>();
            DataTable dt = (new CustomerBLL()).GetAllCustomers;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows) {
                    rtnList.Add(new Customer {
                            CustomerId = Convert.ToInt32(dr("CustomerID")),
                            CustomerName = Convert.ToString(dr("CustomerName"))
                    });
            }
            return rtnList;
    }

}
```

Here is XAML

```
<ComboBox Name="CustomerComboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Width="150" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=CustomerDomainDataSource, Path=Data}" DisplayMemberPath="CustomerName" SelectedValuePath="CustomerId"/>
        <riaControls:DomainDataSource AutoLoad="True" d:DesignData="{d:DesignInstance my1:Customer, CreateList=true}" Height="0" Name="CustomerDomainDataSource" QueryName="GetCustomersQuery" Width="0">
            <riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
                <my:CustomerDomainContext />
            </riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
        </riaControls:DomainDataSource>
```

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you start with these two posts.

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20151228171945/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kylemc/archive/2010/06/18/combobox-sample-for-ria-services.aspx)

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/kylemc/silverlight-combobox-frequently-asked-questions)

There's a sample that shows a number of different configurations as well as code snippets and explanation to get you started.